# How do we calculate the USD price from a swap?

Tags: uniswap

I'm looking at dextools for uniswap and it's showing the price for 1 UNI is USD 3.57238184. How does dextool calculate this? A manual calculation would be great

An example:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xef8e13aea6e1cab7001de4e1d6ffd66828f56d64e551838d82d4f700ce85f16a

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to infer token price from ethereum blockchain UniSwap data?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83701/how-to-infer-token-price-from-ethereum-blockchain-uniswap-data)