# What's the relationship between LP reserves and Swap rate?

Tags: uniswap, decentralized-exchange, pancakeswap

This transaction [transaction](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x529ba9819eaf1adfff5a4e79c253f537998549a89d0d612ec73fb512e4733a30) describes Swap event:

```
amount0_in=14067900000000
amount1_out=393017164305296368
```

This means that the effective trade rate is:

```
trade_rate=round(amount1_out/amount0_in)=27,937
```

Meanwhile, this is the last Sync event before Swap and Sync event after Swap.

Before:

```
reserve0=95594454080845
reserve1=3070347989941780637
```

After:

```
reserve0=109662354080845
reserve1=2677330825636484269
```

The first one describes rate `32,118` and the second one `24,414`. Neither are equal or close to  `27,937`.

Both transactions:

- [0x6e163a94f50cc1c4845880fe0a28cf196446c2fcb64d964441e66a903e2dc51f](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x6e163a94f50cc1c4845880fe0a28cf196446c2fcb64d964441e66a903e2dc51f)
- [0x529ba9819eaf1adfff5a4e79c253f537998549a89d0d612ec73fb512e4733a30](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x529ba9819eaf1adfff5a4e79c253f537998549a89d0d612ec73fb512e4733a30)

What's the relationship between Swap events and reserve values and how was the Swap rate determined?

For what it is worth, I was able to calculate similar output using formula from this [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/83702/70785):

```
reserve0=95594454080845
reserve1=3070347989941780637
amount0_in=14067900000000

round((reserve1 * amount0_in)/(reserve0 + amount0_in))
```

This gives `393875809522191052`, which is close to the expected `393017164305296368`, though not exactly the same.

The difference appears to be 0.21%:

```
a=393,875,809,522,191,052
b=393,017,164,305,296,368

((a-b)/((a+b)/2))*100=0.21
```

That 0.21% resembles [pancakeswap](/questions/tagged/pancakeswap) fee. However, I cannot figure out how to incorporate that into the original formula to get the *exact* same figure.

I even tried to apply the logic from [`getAmountOut`](https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/blob/d769a6d136b74fde82502ec2f9334acc1afc0732/contracts/libraries/PancakeLibrary.sol#L44-L51), but that still gives a different number:

```
amount_in_with_fee=amount_in*998 = 14,039,764,200,000,000
numerator=amount_in_with_fee*reserve1 = 43,106,961,790,726,571,871,605,795,400,000,000
denominator=reserve0*1000+amount_in_with_fee = 109,634,218,280,845,000
amount_out=round(numerator/denominator) = 393,188,937,420,080,150
```

Answer (score 2):

```
amount_in=14067900000000
amount_out=393017164305296368

reserve0=95594454080845
reserve1=3070347989941780637

amount_in_with_fee=amount_in*998-14067900000000*0.5
numerator=amount_in_with_fee*reserve1
denominator=reserve0*1000+amount_in_with_fee
amount_out=round(numerator/denominator) = 393,017,164,305,296,368
```

I figured out the *how*, but not the *why*.

I will leave this unanswered until someone proposes the why it works this way.

Comment: where did you get the `998` for working out the `amount_in_with_fee`? I can see it in the code for `getAmountIn` but wondering is this because the pancake fee is 0.02%, but then why we mulitpling it by half (`*0.5`). https://github.com/pancakeswap/pancake-swap-periphery/blob/d769a6d136b74fde82502ec2f9334acc1afc0732/contracts/libraries/PancakeLibrary.sol#L53